# Add xml subelement with different namespaces than root element using lxml

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, lxml

This is a simplified version of the xml I'm trying to build:

```
<BizData xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:n1="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01 head.003.001.02_DTCC.xsd">
  <Hdr>
   <AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02"             
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02 head.001.001.02.xsd"> 
   </AppHdr>
  </Hdr>
 </BizData>
```

**Python Code**

```
from lxml import etree as etree

if __name__ == '__main__':
attr_qname = etree.QName('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'schemaLocation')
nsmap = {None: 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01',
         'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
         'n1': 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02'
        }
root = etree.Element('BizData',
                     {attr_qname: 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01 head.003.001.02_DTCC.xsd'},
                     nsmap)

hdr = etree.Element('hdr')
attr_qname = etree.QName('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'schemaLocation')
nsmap = {None: 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02',
         'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
         }

app_hdr = etree.Element('AppHdr',
                {attr_qname: 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02 head.001.001.02.xsd'},
                nsmap)
hdr.append(app_hdr)
root.append(hdr)
```

When printing `hdr` before appending to the root I get the correct output:

```
<Hdr>
 <AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02"             
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         
  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02 head.001.001.02.xsd"> 
 </AppHdr>
</Hdr>
```

But after appending to root the namesspaces `xmlns` and `xmlns:xsi` disappear:

```
<BizData xmlns:n1="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
 xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01 head.003.001.02_DTCC.xsd">
 <hdr>
  <AppHdr xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02 head.001.001.02.xsd"/>
 </hdr>
</BizData>
```

I tried using the `set` function to set `xmlns:xsi` but this causes the error `..not a valid attribute...`

Does anybody has an idea?

Comment: `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` is declared on the root element. It is in scope for the whole document and the declaration won't be repeated on any other elements. It is not illegal to repeat it, but I don't think you can force lxml to do that.

Comment: You want two declarations for the `urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02` namespace; first bound to the `n1` prefix on the `BizData` root element and then as the default namespace on `AppHdr`. Why? Having it this way in an XML document is not forbidden as far as I know, but it seems odd.

Comment: @mzjn I agree with you that it is in scope for the whole document, unfortunately I was given this template by the authorities and have to stick to its (unusual) design. Do you know a different/better library than lxml or a way to force this double declaration?

Comment: The XML that you want to create is a bit odd, but it is not breaking any rules as far as I can tell. However, I don't think it is possible to force lxml to output that exact markup. You may have to create the markup "by hand" and treat it as plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DIRTY WORKAROUND**

1. Create Envelope (`BizData`), Header (`Hdr`) and Payload (`Pyld`) as individual `etree.Element`'s
2. Transfer them to strings
3. Combine the strings
4. Write to xml file

This is ignoring any sort of validation but doesn't mess with the namespace. Not ideal, but does the job.